# C# How to code for timeout using client.OpenRead(url)

Tags: c#, timeout

I am running a C# program that processes UDP requests and sends the result to a PHP program which updates a database on my hosted website using the following:

```
client2.QueryString.Add("power", Qpower); // etc. several of these statements 
string url = "http://example.com/processUDPmessage.php";
// Send the database update request 
var stream = client2.OpenRead(url);
```

Once and a while the above OpenRead command times out for whatever reason. Perhaps a hick-up on my home network. I'm not sure.

Right now, I'm running the UDP receive program using the Visual Studio Debugger. If there is a timeout, I can just press "Continue" and it keeps going. I would rather add some code so that if there is a timeout it just keeps trying until the the network issue is resolved.

How do I do this?

If I use Try/Catch, what do I catch and will **throw ex** keep the program running? I want to prevent the program from stopping -- just keep trying to send the command to my PHP program.